# Is there a way to autoexecute code when Pry is triggered?

Tags: ruby, debugging, pry

Is there a way to automatically execute code when `binding.pry` is encountered?

For example, if I want to execute `puts "Hey, I'm debugging!"` every time `binding.pry` is called?

Comment: i don't think that there is something like that built into pry. why do you want to do that?

Comment: Mike H-R answered it. I want to use it to trigger changes to logging features when a debugger is triggered so the application can context-switch without requiring CLI flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I felt like having a look at the code and found something that might be useful, you either have to add it to the gemfile or you might be able to add it to your `.pryrc` (I don't know if this gets called from `binding.pry` or not). From github there appears to be:

```
# @example Adding a hook for the `:before_session` event.
Pry.config.hooks.add_hook(:before_session, :say_hi) do
  puts "hello"
end
```

From [the pry github hooks file](https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/1b078e9d24d27f59c1c06533c0a3f59b659276a5/lib/pry/hooks.rb#L9).

EDIT: Here's an example to register the hook and execute it (i.e. init your app) [from another part of the pry github hooks file](https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/1b078e9d24d27f59c1c06533c0a3f59b659276a5/lib/pry/hooks.rb#L144):**

```
my_hook = Pry::Hooks.new.add_hook(:before_session, :say_hi) { puts "hi!" }
my_hook.exec_hook(:before_session) #=> OUTPUT: "hi!"
```

Comment: BTW, it can go directly in your application init file, rather than in `.pryrc`.  Really useful!